# What happened to VMDepot?

Tags: azure, bitnami, azure-marketplace

I know that bitnami has moved all his images to the Azure Marketplace, but there was others VM on vmdepot. Now there is no simple way to share virtual machines on Azure.

Comment: Define "share". You *can* put a VM in Marketplace without charging.. You *can* create your own images. Are you looking for a specific VM?

Comment: By "share" i mean,  create a VM that anybody can use without asking you to authorize access. Like in the AWS world, you  put the AMI in public access, then you promote the  AMIs ID (it's quite easy).

Comment: Finaly, Azure really helped us to published in its marketplace :-) : thanks for that. The publish process is a bit more complicate, because of Azure policies. But anyway, Marketplace is very good place to highlt your products, far better than VMDepot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned, Microsoft Azure decide to removed their old VM Depot Marketplace and all the Bitnami Images have been moved to their new Marketplace:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/.

You can create your a virtual machine image for the Azure Marketplace and publish it following the guide below:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/marketplace-publishing-vm-image-creation/

Comment: The original question itself is off-topic. Having further discussion here is just... more off-topic.

Comment: @DavidMakogon if ***offtopic***  you can ***flag*** _the question_